# Web app vulnerability scanning: how many URLs to check?

Tags: web-application, vulnerability-scanners

Scanning all of spidered URLs with a tool such as OWASP Zap can be computationally expensive on large apps. Have there been any studies on the adequate number of URLs (just the unique resources) to scan to have, let's say, 95% confidence level about the test's accuracy? If not, maybe somebody can share stories from experience? I often deliberately exclude large chunks of spidered URLs in my tests for efficiency, but would like to hear from others to see if any kind of methodic approach has been invented. Many thanks

Comment: Do you mean the number of URLs or the number of URLs that point to similar resources? Consider Stack Exchange, for example - URLs are of the format `https://subdomain.stackexchange.com/questions/{id}/{optional-slug}` for questions. Given a specific user with specific permissions (which result in various links, forms, etc. on tha page), you probably don't have to crawl every question. However, just because you crawled N questions doesn't mean you shouldn't crawl other pages of other types to find vulnerabilities.

Comment: Resources - thanks for pointing out. Edited.

Comment: This question makes no sense. Accuracy? Confidence? Percentages? You want to scan a *subset* of *resources* to derive a statistically significant sample to determine ... what exactly? If a house has 10 doors, and you check 9 of them to see if they are locked, what confidence level ***should*** you have that all doors are locked? If unlocked, the 10th door defeats the security of the rest. The only thing you can say when testing a ***sample*** is the results of the sample. You need to highlight what has not been tested.

Comment: @schroder In practice, efficiency is sometimes as important as accuracy. I have large apps where comprehensive scanning takes on the order of a week to complete. For me it makes sense to try optimize testing by using statistical approaches. For example, Monte Carlo is a known method to reduce sampling size without which the atomic bomb would have never been invented. I was hoping something similar is used in the industry, but, according to you, everyone just bangs the snot out of targets no matter how long it takes.

Answer (score 0):

**Introduction**

Penetration testing is a process and it can be done in many ways. To answer the first question, it is essential to understand that scanning will aid in finding the bugs in a fast pace method, but it's not a final solution to identify the vulnerabilities or ensure the test accuracy. The major problem with scanners available in the market is the number of false positives and their elimination. So it's not practically possible to stick with that scanner results and confirm the test was a huge success.

From my experience, the best term to use is test coverage over test accuracy. Even if you scan the entire crawled URLs the test coverage will stand less. Consider ZAP or Burpsuite, the way the scanner works is dependent on payloads and responses. The tech stack and defensive techniques are expanding at the same rate of expansion of attacks as well. That being said, every payload and method used by the scanner will be already blocked if there is a WAF.

Consider a scenario where an SQLi was identified by Burpsuite and you exploited it using SQLMap or manual method. The next day after submitting the report they implement a WAF and say it has been fixed, but the Burpsuite scanner won't be able to do anything on this, even if this is scanner separately it will be blocked by the WAF. But with real IP from the DNS history you can bypass and exploit it again since the root cause for SQLi was not fixed.

**Answer**

Scanning is a support and it's not going to give you 95% confidence. Every little function is an entry point for a vulnerability.

**What to do?**

1. Walkthrough the application by turning on the proxy and going to each and every function at least once. At the end of looking into every function do a spider with depth 4 and wait for it to finish. Select the entire domain tree and start the scanning. It's better to check the crawled URLs and identify similar URLs as mentioned by Thomas in the comments and exclude them from the scanning. I have not actively used ZAP, but Burpsuite has the feature to exclude the URLs and extensions before starting the scanning.
2. Find the functions/URLs that take inputs from the user. Scan only those URLs that have the chance for a vulnerability. For example: Showing records (SQLi), Form submission (XSS), Server Response (HTTP Resmuggling), XML Parsing (XXE), and Resource fetching (SSRF/RFI) . Scan these URLs only.

   - NB: Vulnerabilities are not limited to the mentioned list
3. Add extensions (Burpsuite) along with a native scanner to identify valuable items like keys in JS files, Cloud buckets etc... This will help you to have more things on your table to assess over the standalone front-end application.

**Conclusion**

There are many ways to attack but it's all about how we mix the methods and leverage our techniques. No scanner can get you results better than manual testing, because of its nature of work.

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the question entirely. It's not about the effectiveness of the tests carried out (or payloads or tools), but about the coverage.

Comment: I got the question right I hope, I have made a detailed explanation, the title of the question itself is about scanning and how should the scanning be completed. He wants to know whether scanning all spidered URLs is going to give him the expected results and the approach others are taking while testing an application.